# How to save data in the link table using jpa

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two master table named person and department. I had also created one link table called person_department. The design of the table is as below.

```
Person Table
------------------
person_id  varchar primary key
first_name varchar
last_name  varchar 

Department Table
----------------------------------
dept_id   varchar primary key
dept_name varchar

Persone_department Table
----------------------------------
person_dept_id varchar  primary key
person_id      varchar  foreign key person table
dept_id        varchar  foreign key dept table

The classes for the above design is as below.

@Entity
Class Persoon {
    @Id
    String id;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="last_name")
    String lastName;
}

@Entity
Class Department {
   @Id
   String departmentId;
   
   @column(name="dept_name")
   String deptName;
}

@Entity
Class PersonDepartment {
   @Id
   String personDeptId;

   @ManyToOne
   @Column(name="person_id")
   List<String> personId;

   @ManyToOne
   @Column(name="dept_id")
   List<String> deptId;
}
```

One person can work in multiple department and one department can have multiple person. I have below three use cases.

1. fetch person's department.
2. add person to a new department.
3. list all person of a department.

Could anyone please help me on how to implement this use cases ?
When I'm trying to save the data in person_department table I'm getting error.

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: @hitch.united When I'm trying to insert it is not generating the correct insert query. I'm doing as below.

`Person p = personrepository.getById(1);`
`DepartMent d = departmentRespository.getById(1);`
`PersonDepartment pd = new PersonDepartment();`
`pd.setPerson(p);`
`pd.setDepartment(d);`
`personDepartmentRepositry.saveAndFlush(pd);`

It is generating the insert statement as below.

`insert into person_department (person_department_id, person_id) values (?, ?);`

It is not inserting the department_id in the table.